# One column in a vb.net Datagridview should not allow paste of non-integers

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview and one of the columns is a Quantity column that should only allow integers. No negative symbols or decimal points. I have prevented the user from typing in any characters but they can paste them in. I could stop this in validation but I would ideally like to not even show characters that are pasted in. How would I detect and remove pasted in letters and in what event?

Ideally I would also like for only the paste to not work, so if the field already had a 2 in it and they pasted "test" then the 2 would remain, although that isn't as important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
'Set a flag to show when the form has finished initialising
Dim initialising As Boolean = True

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Form is initialised so set boolean to false
    initialising = False
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
'Only process once the form is initialised as values don't exist yet!    
If Not initialising Then
        If Not IsNothing(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) Then
            'If the clipboard contains text
            If Clipboard.ContainsText Then
                ' Check to see if the value of the cell matches whats in the clipboard
                If CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = Clipboard.GetText Then
                    'You know its been pasted
                    If Not IsNumeric(CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value)) Then
                        'This value should be rejected
                    Else
                        'This value is allowed
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

See my commentated code for an explanation.

I'm not sure you will want to do it on this event as it doesn't fire the event until the user leaves the cell. Hopefully however my approach of checking the value against what is in the clipboard might help you to identify if its a pasted value.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to implement a validating method and call it in some of the [DataGridView's events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx) (I'm thinking KeyDown/Keypress and MouseClick).

I think it's bad practice, because you'll be struggling to find more ways in which the user can trick your application; most apps nowadays let the user input whatever they want, but keep the user from completing her task until she has sanitized her input. Most also give clear on-screen instructions on how to do so.

Comment: I agree that it could be bad practice but it isn't really up to me for this one. If I were to implement it in say the Mouseclick I wouldn't know if they pasted in would I? Then how would I distinguish that it was pasted text?

Comment: Keep the user from right clicking. That was my idea. If they can be allowed to paste, but shouldn't paste negatives or text, then I'm out of ideas, but I still suggest you read about each and every event in that documentation page. Maybe you'll find something that will help you.

Comment: Yeah because sadly they still need to be able to paste numbers.

Comment: On second thought, you could read what the user has copied from somewhere else (there is a class for that) during right click, and disable the cell if the value is invalid. Then you reenable the cell again in the CellValidated event.

Comment: P.S.: whomever wrote that requirement is stupid. I would look for a better job if that person happens to be your boss.

Comment: No he's not my boss but he is an ex-programmer who thinks he knows best. When he picks a requirement it's usually not up for discussion. Maybe I will try to convince him though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub
```

Comment: But how will this prevent me from pasting into the field from the context menu > paste.

Comment: TextBox1.ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip .. in form_load event